# What is the MSBuild 2010 script file equivalent of the command line switch /t:Package

Tags: msbuild

I can see that MSBuild makes use of the /t:Package on the command line, but what's the euivalent for including this option in an msbuild script file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you invoking an msbuild script from another script using the MsBuild task? If so, the parameter you want to use is Targets http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in a build script file is to use the MsBuild task.  See link below.

[Msdn Build Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx)

Comment: Sorry colin, @fsimonazzi got there first. Thanks for your response though.